# Online file viewer (all formats)

Tags: ms-office, google-docs, google-docs-api, google-document-viewer, office-web-components

I have some files on S3 and would like to view those files in web. Problem is that the files are not public and I dont want them to be public. Google doc viewer works but condition is, files should be public.

Can I use office web apps to show in browser. Since the files are private, I do not want to store any data on Microsoft servers. It looks like even google doc viewer stores the info while parsing.

What is the cleanest way?

Thanks.

Comment: This is not so much a programming question, at least how it is put at this time, so you are probably better served if you ask your question on http://www.superuser.com.

Answer (score 0):

I have looked around for something similiar before and there are some apps you can install locally (CyberDuck, S3 Browser, etc).  In the browser has been limited until recently (full disclosure I worked on this project).

S3 LENS - https://www.s3lens.com/

Answer (score 0):

I probably get a minus here, but also Microsoft has an online viewer, which works the same way: the file needs to be publicly accessible.

Here is the link: https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx

What I cloud add is that those files need to be publicly accessible only for a short period, i.e. until the page gets opened. So you cloud trick them by uploading the file to be viewed to a public temporary storage in a randomly generated folder and give that url to the online viewer.

Of course this is not that safe, since the file will get as some point to the temp storage and then to Google or Microsoft, but the random path names offer some degree of safety.

I've created recently a small glitch app, which demonstrates what I just explained: https://honeysuckle-eye.glitch.me/

It uploads local files to a temp storage and then opens the viewer from that temp storage; the temp storage only last for one download, so it is pretty safe.